# How to add a dropdown list to Mals-e gift voucher form

Tags: html, forms, methods, drop-down-menu

Using the example code from Mals-e website for gift vouchers, how would I go about changing the `VALUE="15.00"` to a dropdown list where a customer could instead select from a list of amounts?

**Voucher Example Code from Mals-e website:**

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://ww#.aitsafe.com/cf/voucher.cfm">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="userid" VALUE="gg12345">
<INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="gift_amount" VALUE="15.00">
Name: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="gift_name">
Email: <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="gift_email">
Message: <TEXTAREA name="gift_message"></TEXTAREA>
<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Buy Me">
</FORM>
```

I've been trying to figure out how to include the following code, but when I do, shipping is then added in the shopping cart:

```
<select>
<option>Amount:</option>
<option value="$10 Gift Voucher for - :10">$10.00</option>
<option value="$25 Gift Voucher for - :25">$25.00</option>
<option value="$50 Gift Voucher for - :50">$50.00</option>
<option value="$75 Gift Voucher for - :75">$75.00</option>
<option value="$100 Gift Voucher for - :100">$100.00</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your wish correctly then you'll want to:

- remove the *hidden* `gift_amount` input
- move your `<select>...</select>` code to somewhere within your `<form>` (where-ever you want it)
- change `<select>` to `<select name="gift_amount">` so it uses the same name as the *hidden* input used to
- For each of the `<option>`s, flip the `value` and the contents around, and remove the `$` signs,

for example:

```
<option value="$10 Gift Voucher for - :10">$10.00</option>
```

should be

```
<option value="10.00">$10 Gift Voucher for - :10</option>
```

and that should be it.

Comment: Your suggestions worked great. Thank you!!

Comment: good good, nice work